# EF 6 How to set up a 1:M relationship with Surrogate Keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF6 (via code first) against an existing db.  The underlying DB has no FK's in it.  The entities are defined with an identity pk, but can also be referenced by a surrogate value (RefId).

Assuming I have:

```
public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string RefId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }

}

public class CartItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string RefId { get; set; }
    public string CartRefId {get;set;}

    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
 }

public class CartMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cart>
{
    public CartMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}

public class CartItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CartItem>
{
    public CartItemMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        HasRequired(t => t.Cart)
            .WithMany(t => t.CartItems)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.CartRefId);
    }
}
```

How can I tell EF that it should be joining the CartItem to Cart based on

```
 Cart.RefId = CartItem.CartRefId
```

By default EF will attempt to join

```
Cart.Id == CartItem.CartRefId
```

because Cart.Id is the Key of the Cart entity.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the EF will try this: Cart.Id == CartItem.CartRefId because the types arent the same. So, is not possible to map to have relationships without PK, if you need the Id fields to be autoincrement you could do some like this:

```
public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RefId { get; set; } // PK
    public virtual List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }

}

public class CartItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string RefId { get; set; } // PK
    public string CartRefId { get; set; }

    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
}

public class CartMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cart>
{
    public CartMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.RefId);
        Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class CartItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CartItem>
{
    public CartItemMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.RefId);
        Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(t => t.Cart)
            .WithMany(t => t.CartItems)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.CartRefId);
    }
}
```

If not, other way could be assumes the default mapping with Id PK, then you can use a join query:

```
    var q = from c in db.Carts
            join i in db.CartItens on c.RefId equals i.CartRefId
            select i;
```